# Getting Undefined when using SELECT as an SQL statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

```
var Type={
selectAll: function (callback) {
    function txFunction(tx) {
        var options = [];
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM type;";
        tx.executeSql(sql, options, callback, errorHandler);
    }

    db.transaction(txFunction, errorHandler, successTransaction);
},
}
```

All i'm getting are undefined when there is data in the Web SQL

Comment: Hopefully I'm missing something here - Where is this code executed? If it is on the client, this looks like a really bad idea...

Comment: i tried to use var types= Type.selectAll();